# Uniform distribution question of choosing from set

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> A number $X$ is picked at random from the set $\{ 2,3, \cdots , k \}$. Having picked $X$, another number $Y$ is picked at random from the set $\{1,2, \cdots , X-1 \}$. Find the probability distribution of $Y$.

I can understand that it will be a uniform distribution, but cannot figure out the exact expression.

Comment: Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

The hardest part here is the interpretation of the assignment in terms of conditional probabilities. We actually have
$$
\mathbb P\left(Y=j\mid X=\ell\right)=\frac1{\ell-1},\quad 1\leqslant j\leqslant \ell-1 \leqslant k-1.
$$
Since you also know that $\mathbb P\left(X=\ell\right)=1/(k-1)$, you can find $\mathbb P\left(Y=j, X=\ell\right)$ hence using the law of total probabilities, $\mathbb P\left(Y=j\right)$.

Comment: Had come up with the expression, but was facing trouble on the conditions. Ok